# On integral closedness of formal power series ring over an integrally closed domain satisfying Krull intersection principle

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, formal-power-series, integral-extensions

Let $R$ be a normal domain (i.e. an integral domain integrally closed in its fraction field) such that for every non-unit $t\in R$, $\cap_{n\ge 1} (t^n)=(0)$ ; then is it true that $R[[X]]$ is normal (i.e. integrally closed in its fraction field) ?

If this is not true in general, what if we strengthen the hypothesis to say $\cap_{n\ge 1} J^n=(0)$ for every proper ideal $J$ of $R$ ?

Comment: If $R[[X]]$ is integrally closed, then $R$ is integrally closed and $\cap_{n\ge 1} (t^n)=(0)$ for every non-unit $t\in R$, but the converse doesn't hold. See [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-122-02/S0002-9947-1966-0202753-9/S0002-9947-1966-0202753-9.pdf).

Comment: @user26857: thanks, I will take a look into that ... and what if we assume the stronger condition that $\cap_{n\ge 1} J^n=(0)$ for every proper ideal $J$ ?